# Need some support on Python for string append/replacement

Tags: scripting, python, python3

I am writing a python script to replace/append certain strings with their equivalents..

Actual string:

```
  Name = "com.icon.t2p"
  Object = "/com/icon/t2p/host"
```

Expected Output :

```
Name = "com.icon.rma"
Object = "/com/icon/rma/Objectname/host"
```

Current Output:

```
 Name = "com.icon.rma"
 Object = "/com/icon.rma/host"
```

I ran below in my python script :

```
 cmdStr="sed -i 's/com.icon.t2p/com.icon.rma/g' /local/run.ini"
 subprocess.call(cmdStr,shell=True)
 cmdStr="sed -i 's/Object=\/com\/icon\/t2p\/host/Object=\/com\/icon\/rma\/Objectname\/host/g' /local/run.ini"
 subprocess.call(cmdStr,shell=True)
```

Looks like I am making some mistake as the append of Objectname is not happening..

What can be the way to fix it?

Comment: The obvious issue is that your input shows whitespace around the assignment operator: your second RE does not appear to allow for that.

Answer (score 1):

It is useless to call from python bash text editing tool

```
Name = Name.rsplit('.', 1)
Object = Object.split('/')
Name[1] = Object[2] = "rma"
Object.insert(3, "Objectname")
Name = '.'.join(Name)
Object = '/'.join(Object)
```

--

```
Name = Name.replace('t2p', 'rma')
Object = Object.replace('t2p', 'rma/Objectname')
```

Comment: As per my understanding "Actual string" in /local/run.ini should be replaced with "Expected Output"..So we need to insert the new strings into /local/run.ini... how are you planning to do that?

Comment: @JagannathDas you are free to read file into python script, change it and re-write it so as to use the bash tools.